# Complex string operation

Tags: javascript, string, function

Following is the script to input only alphabets, numbers, space, del, backspace. In this code I need to make change that if "input" at first position is a "white space" and there are no further `aphanumeric characters` in the User Input, it should return false else `true`.

JS

```
function usrInp(evt) {
var char = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (char > 64 && inp < 91 || char > 96 && char < 123 || char > 47 && char < 58 || char     == 127 || char == 8 || char == 32) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

FORM HTML

```
 <form name="one" id="one">
  <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" onkeypress="return    usrInp(event)" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression?

Comment: @Fermin How to implement it here... ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not regex?

```
return input.match(/^[\w\s]*$/g) != null
```

This returns true if the input contains only A-Z, 0-9, spaces or underscores.

Comment: But I need to check if "input" at first position is a "white space" and there are no further aphanumeric characters in the User Input, it should return false `and for all other cases` it should return true. That means, string can have `White Spaces` further on...

Comment: @sandbox So starts with a space? And no other letters or numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Using the keypress event won't capture the backspace key, you would need to use keyup for that. If you want to get to the ascii value of a key being pressed though, you can use:

```
function usrInp(evt) {
  var char = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  return String.fromCharCode(char).match(/^[A-Z0-9 _]*$/);
}
```